# Kotlin Coroutines with timeout

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently writing a test-function which should run a block or (when a certain timeout is reached) throws an exception.

I was trying this with `Coroutines` in Kotlin but ended up with a mixture of `Coroutines` and `CompletableFuture`:

```
fun <T> runBlockWithTimeout(maxTimeout: Long, block: () -> T ): T {
    val future = CompletableFuture<T>()

    // runs the coroutine
    launch { block() }

    return future.get(maxTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure if this is the intended way to solve that problem in kotlin.

I also tried other approaches:

```
runBlocking {
    withTimeout(maxTimeout) {
        block()
    }
}
```

But this seems not to work as soon as the `block` calls e.g. `Thread.sleep(...)`

So is the `CompletableFuture` approach the way to go or is there a better one?

**update 1**
What I want to achieve:

Async Integration-Test code (like receiving data from RabbitMq) should be tested somehow like this:

```
var rabbitResults: List = ... // are filled async via RabbitListeners
...
waitMax(1000).toSucceed {
    assertThat(rabbitResults).hasSize(1)
}
waitMax(1000).toSucceed {
    assertThat(nextQueue).hasSize(3)
}
...
```

Comment: If you are using some test library, it might already have the timeout feature. For example, with JUnit you can set the `@Test(timeout=5000)` annotation on a test method.

Comment: I updated the description to make it better understandable what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`withTimeout { ... }` is designed to *cancel* the ongoing operation on timeout, which is only possible if the operation in question is *cancellable*.

The reason it works with `future.get(timeout, unit)` is because it only *waits* with timeout. It does not actually cancel or abort in any way your background operation which still continues to execute after timeout had elapsed.

If you want to mimick similar behavior with coroutines, then you should *wait* with timeout, like this:

```
val d = async { block() } // run the block code in background
withTimeout(timeout, unit) { d.await() } // wait with timeout
```

It works properly because `await` is a cancellable function which you can verify by reading [its API documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-deferred/await.html).

However, if you want to actually cancel the ongoing operation on timeout, then then you should implement your code in asyncronous and cancellable way. Cancellation is *cooperative*, so, to start, the underlying library that you are using in your code has to provide asynchronous API that supports cancellation of ongoing operation.

You can read more about cancellation and timeouts in the corresponding section of the [coroutines guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-and-timeouts) and watch the KotlinConf's [Deep Dive into Coroutines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8) on how to integrate coroutines with asynchronous libraries.

Comment: Roman is there something like d.await(timeout) such that it does not cancel but rather wakes up from current suspended function giving chance to check something and if needed do d.cancel()... i want d to keep working until cancelled manually

Comment: Use withTimeout(timeout) { d.await() } for that purpose - it does exactly that. async task is still working after timeout.

Comment: I believe thats what i tried to do, if you have a minute please take a look at my attempt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370415/kotlin-coroutine-future-await-with-timeout-no-cancellation

Comment: Here's the current location of the Cancellation & Timeouts section of the Coroutines Guide: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html

Comment: coroutine should be cancelable !!! - it is important

Comment: Can `runInterruptible()` be used instead?