# Kotlin coroutine future await with timeout (no cancellation)

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, completable-future

Given we have a `CompletableFuture f`, in kotlin suspendable scope we can call `f.await()` and we will suspend until its done.

I'm having trouble implementing a similar function with signature `f.await(t)` which must suspend for maximum `t` milliseconds or return sooner if future did complete within that duration (whichever happens first).

Here is what i tried.

```
/**
 * Suspend current method until future is done or specified duration expires,
 * whichever happens first without cancelling the future.
 * Returns true if its done, false otherwise.
 */
suspend fun <T> ListenableFuture<T>.await(duration: Long): Boolean {
   val future = this
   try {
      withTimeout(duration) {
         withContext(NonCancellable) { // this does not help either
            future.await() // i do not expect the future itself to be cancelled
         }
      }
   } catch (t: TimeoutCancellationException) {
      // we expected this
   } catch (e: Throwable) {
      e.printStackTrace()
   }

   return future.isDone

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
   val future = GlobalScope.future {
      try {
         repeat(5) {
            println("computing")
            delay(500)
         }
         println("complete")
      } finally {
         withContext(NonCancellable) {
            println("cancelling")
            delay(500)
            println("cancelled")
         }
      }
   }

   for (i in 0..10) {
      if (future.await(2000)) {
         println("checking : done")
      } else {
         println("checking : not done")
      }
   }
}
```

I also need a similar function for a job. But maybe solution for this will also help me with that...

Output for this is

```
computing
computing
computing
computing
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
cancelling
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
checking : done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i came up with, i believe this is not a good solution since, i'm most likely creating a lot of garbage for rather primitive task.

```
suspend fun <T> CompletableFuture<T>.await(duration: Millis): Boolean {
   val timeout = CompletableFuture<Unit>()

   GlobalScope.launch {
      delay(duration)
      timeout.complete(Unit)
   }

   val anyOfTwo = CompletableFuture.anyOf(this, timeout)
   anyOfTwo.await()
   return this.isDone
}


fun main() = runBlocking {
   val future = CompletableFuture<String>()

   GlobalScope.launch {
      delay(2000)
      println("setting the result (future now ${future.isDone})")
      future.complete("something")
   }

   while (future.isNotDone()) {
      println("waiting for the future to complete for the next 500ms")
      val isDone = future.await(500)

      if (isDone) {
         println("future is done")
         break
      } else {

         println("future not done")
      }
   }

   Unit
}
```

this will give output of

```
waiting for the future to complete for the next 500ms
future not done
waiting for the future to complete for the next 500ms
future not done
waiting for the future to complete for the next 500ms
future not done
waiting for the future to complete for the next 500ms
setting the result (future now false)
future is done
```

which is what we wanted...

Answer (score 2):

I've written some test code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val future = calculateAsync()
    val result = future.await(2000)
    println("result=$result")
}

suspend fun <T> CompletableFuture<T>.await(duration: Long): T? {
    val future = this
    var result: T? = null
    try {
        withTimeout(duration) {
            result = future.await()
        }
    } catch (t: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        println("timeout exception")
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return result
}

@Throws(InterruptedException::class)
fun calculateAsync(): CompletableFuture<String> {
    val completableFuture = CompletableFuture<String>()

    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit {
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        println("after sleep")
        completableFuture.complete("Completed")
    }

    return completableFuture
}
```

After we run this code we will get an output:

```
timeout exception
result=null
after sleep
```

We see that our extension function `await` returns `null` because we set timeout to 2000 milliseconds but `CompletableFuture` completes after 3000 milliseconds. In this case `CompletableFuture` is cancelled(its `isCancelled` property returns `true`), but the Thread which we ran in `calculateAsync` function continues executing (we see it in the logs `after sleep`).

If we set timeout duration to 4000 milliseconds `future.await(4000)` in the `main` function, we will see next output:

```
after sleep
result=Completed
```

Now we have some result because `CompletableFuture` is executed faster than 4000 millisecond.

Comment: it is being cancelled, completable future has no relation to the thread that runs the code you submitted, after the very first timeout the future object isDone... check yourself, or put a debug breakpoint in cancel method of completable future...

CF does not interrupt or terminate the underlying thread in any way...

Comment: or you can simply check the future.isDone() after the first early timeout... it will be true

Comment: I've made some edits to my answer. There is also `isCancelled` property in `CompletableFuture`. It returns `true` if executing exceeds the timeout, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Sergey i appreciate the effort but thats not the goal, we want the future not to be touched, we simply need a way to occasionally check if something completed (be that future or a job), yes we could use delays in a loop but in that case if future completes we still loose that delay time... 
Please see the solution i have below, it works does not touch the future and does exactly what we want but i'm not sure how good the solution is performance wise...