# How to call asynchronous request synchronously with a timeout value?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have to synchronously call an asynchronous api request. Since this api request takes long time to answer, I also want to set a timeout to fail the api-request and continue with null. Here's my code to call this api:

```
private suspend fun call(
    accessStage: AccessStage,
): Response? = withContext<Response?>(Dispatchers.IO) {

    return@withContext withTimeoutOrNull(1000) {

        suspendCoroutine<Response?> { continuation ->

            val request = External3rdPartyApi.newRequest(
                accessStage
            ) { response, throwable ->

                continuation.resume(response)
            }

            request.parameters = hashMapOf<String, String>().apply {
                put["token"] = External3rdPartyApi.TOKEN
                put["salt"] = External3rdPartyApi.calculateSalt(accessStage)
            }
            request.executeAsync()
        }
    }
}
```

I can't change how `External3rdPartyApi` works.

I think above code looks evil. Also, I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47641886/3682535):

> `withTimeout { ... }` is designed to cancel the ongoing operation on timeout, which is only possible if the operation in question is *cancellable*.

So, should I use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` instead of `suspendCoroutine`?

How can I write it in a better way?

Comment: I think your code looks allright. You only need to use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` when you get a cancel event from your third party api and you wanna then cancel the coroutine itself. Otherwise `suspendCoroutine` with a timeout is fine.

Comment: @ChristianB Hi, thanks. One more question. `External3rdPartyApi.newRequest` gives me a throwable too if an exception occurs. If it didn't handle thrown exceptions, would it make sense to use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` then? Even if I handle thrown exceptions myself, I would just need to throw a canceling exception to stop the coroutine, right?

Comment: The `continuation` from the `suspendCoroutine` offers you either `resume(value)` or `resumeWithException(exception)`, which lets you "Resumes the execution of the corresponding coroutine so that the exception is re-thrown right after the last suspension point." With `suspendCancellableCoroutine` you can call `cancel(throwable)`. I guess both have kind of the same effect. But I am not super sure here. Let me know which works for you :)

Comment: I did some research and posted an answer. Some of my comments above where not so correct. Still learning every day new details of Coroutines ;)

Comment: Since you don't perform blocking ops, you have no need for `withContext` in there.

Comment: I recommend building a mini-library of extension suspend functions for your third party library so your main application code can cleanly use them without having `suspendCancellableCoroutine` littered everywhere.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I used `withContext` to run the code on background dispatcher. It, also, returns me the result. What should I use otherwise? If I have understood you wrong, please add an answer explaining this improvement or suggest me an article. It will help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, this is kinda part of a wrapper around it. I am planning to use builder pattern to create settings like timeouts and cancelation-lability and then, enqueue requests. I was having this issue, so I put together a sample to ask the question that might answer most of my queries.

Comment: All you need a thread for is to submit the async request, this happens almost instantly. You don't need a background thread for that. Until you get the response, no thread is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `suspendCoroutine` is fine if you can't (or do not wanna) handle cancelation of the Coroutine. But because you have a timeout, you should consider using [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) and handle the cancelation event to stop the work (in the third party function - if you can).

```kotlin
suspendCancellableCoroutine<T> { continuation ->
  continuation.invokeOnCancellation { throwable ->
    // now you could stop your (third party) work  
  }        
}
```

When your third party function throws an exception, you could try-catch it and finish your continuation using either resuming with the `exception` or return a `null` value (depends on your use case):

```kotlin
suspendCancellableCoroutine<T?> { continuation ->
  try {
    continuation.resume(thirdParty.call())
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    // resume with exception
    continuation.resumeWithException(e)
    // or just return null and swallow the exception
    continuation.resume(null)
  }   
}
```

**Lets put all together**

```kotlin
suspend fun call(): Response? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  return@withContext withTimeoutOrNull(1000L) {
    return@withTimeoutOrNull suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
      try {
        continuation.resume(External3rdPartyApi.newRequest(accessStage))
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        // resume with exception
        continuation.resumeWithException(e)
        
        // or just return null and swallow the exception
        continuation.resume(null)
      }
         
      // in case the coroutine gets cancelled - because of timeout or something else
      continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
        // stop all the work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to learn great deal about coroutines by understanding how cancellation and suspension works.