# Logic after withTimeout kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My code logic looks something like this

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    withTimeout(60000L) {
        repeat(10) {
            //some logic
        }
    }

}
```

I need to `errorLiveData.postValue(TIMEOUT_ERROR)`
when logic inside withTimeout wasn't complete and timeout time ended, how can I do it smoothly, couldn't find anywhere. Pls don't suggest launching 60000L delay.

Comment: Just to understand, you want to do something in case the timeout ends and the logic inside the repeat does not finish?

Comment: @tomerpacific I updated question details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Coroutines with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635367/kotlin-coroutines-with-timeout)

Comment: @tomerpacific maybe I didn't understand something, but I read it a few times and I don't think it helps

Answer (score 4):

Here `withTimeoutOrNull` comes into the picture . `withTimeoutOrNull` return mentioned value if code is done within that time otherwise null will be return so your code must look like this

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val result = withTimeoutOrNull(60000L) {
        repeat(10) {
            //some logic
        }
        "Done"
    }
    
    if(result == null){
      // code couldn't complete .. it is timeout
    }else{
      // code executed completely .. it is success
    }

}
```

For More information , follow offical doc here
https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout-or-null.html

Comment: You don't need `"Done"`, because `repeat` already returns `Unit`, which can be distinguished from `null`

Answer (score -1):

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        try {
            withTimeout(5000) {
                // your code here
            }
        } catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        // code when time is out
        } finally {
        // code to execute after withTimeout completes, regardless of whether it timed out or not
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, this was acceptable, maybe will help someone

Comment: This can lead to hard-to-debug issues in case of nested `withTimeout`, because the caught `TimeoutCancellationException` could come from an outer `withTimeout` call. Also, using exceptions for control flow is not advised in general. We should prefer `withTimeoutOrNull` + a null check to act on the timeout case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            withTimeout(5000L) {
                //your logic go here
            }
        } catch (e : TimeoutCancellationException) {
            // Time out exceeded
            errorLiveData.postValue(TIMEOUT_ERROR)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This can lead to hard-to-debug issues in case of nested `withTimeout`, because the caught `TimeoutCancellationException` could come from an outer `withTimeout` call. Also, using exceptions for control flow is not advised in general. We should prefer `withTimeoutOrNull` + a null check to act on the timeout case.